# CouchDB replicate to apache2 server - "failed to replicate" - Linux

Tags: database, connection, couchdb, replicate

I got couchDB running on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and accessed Futon locally. I tried replicating my DB remotely to my server and got the error:

Replication failed: {{error,{2,"lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n"}},
 <<"\n\nhttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n  \n  \n    \n    Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works\n    \n  * {\n    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\n    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\n  }\n\n  body, html {\n    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;\n\n    background-color: #D8DBE2;\n\n    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;\n    font-size: 11pt;\n    text-align: center;\n  }\n\n  div.main_page {\n    position: relative;\n    display: table;\n\n    width: 800px;\n\n    margin-bottom: 3px;\n    margin-left: auto;\n    margin-right: auto;\n    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\n\n    border-width: 2px;\n    border-color: #212738;\n    border-style: solid;\n\n    background-color: #FFFFFF;\n\n    text-align: center;\n  }\n\n  div.page_header {\n    height: 99px;\n    width: 100%;\n\n    background-color: #F5F6F7;\n  }\n\n  div.page_header span {\n    margin: 15px 0px 0px 50px;\n\n    font-size: 180%;\n    font-weight: bold;\n  }\n\n  div.page_header img {\n    margin: 3px 0px 0px 40px;\n\n    border: 0px 0px 0px;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents {\n    clear: left;\n\n    min-width: 200px;\n\n    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;\n\n    background-color: #FFFFFF;\n\n    text-align: left;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents_item {\n    clear: left;\n\n    width: 100%;\n\n    margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;\n\n    background-color: #FFFFFF;\n\n    color: #000000;\n    text-align: left;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents_item a {\n    margin: 6px 0px 0px 6px;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section {\n    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;\n\n    background-color: #FFFFFF;\n\n    text-align: left;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text {\n    padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;\n\n    color: #000000;\n    font-size: 100%;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text pre {\n    margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;\n    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;\n\n    border-width: 1px;\n    border-style: dotted;\n    border-color: #000000;\n\n    background-color: #F5F6F7;\n\n    font-style: italic;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text p {\n    margin-bottom: 6px;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text ul, div.content_section_text li {\n    padding: 4px 8px 4px 16px;\n  }\n\n  div.section_header {\n    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;\n\n    background-color: #8E9CB2;\n\n    color: #FFFFFF;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    font-size: 112%;\n    text-align: center;\n  }\n\n  div.section_header_red {\n    background-color: #CD214F;\n  }\n\n  div.section_header_grey {\n    background-color: #9F9386;\n  }\n\n  .floating_element {\n    position: relative;\n    float: left;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents_item a,\n  div.content_section_text a {\n    text-decoration: none;\n    font-weight: bold;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents_item a:link,\n  div.table_of_contents_item a:visited,\n  div.table_of_contents_item a:active {\n    color: #000000;\n  }\n\n  div.table_of_contents_item a:hover {\n    background-color: #000000;\n\n    color: #FFFFFF;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text a:link,\n  div.content_section_text a:visited,\n   div.content_section_text a:active {\n    background-color: #DCDFE6;\n\n    color: #000000;\n  }\n\n  div.content_section_text a:hover {\n    background-color: #000000;\n\n    color: #DCDFE6;\n  }\n\n  div.validator {\n  }\n    \n  \n  \n    \n      \n        \n        \n          Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page\n        \n      \n\n        \n          TABLE OF CONTENTS\n        </div>\n        \n          About</a>\n        </div>\n        \n          Changes</a>\n        </div>\n        \n          Scope</a>\n        </div>\n        \n          Config files</a>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n-->\n      \n\n\n        \n          \n          It works!\n        \n        \n

\n                This is the default welcome page used to test the correct \n                operation of the Apache2 server after installation on Ubuntu systems.\n                It is based on the equivalent page on Debian, from which the Ubuntu Apache\n                packaging is derived.\n                If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at\n                this site is working properly. You should **replace this file** (located at\n                /var/www/html/index.html) before continuing to operate your HTTP server.\n

\n\n\n

\n                If you are a normal user of this web site and don't know what this page is\n                about, this probably means that the site is currently unavailable due to\n                maintenance.\n                If the problem persists, please contact the site's administrator.\n

\n\n        \n        \n          \n                Configuration Overview\n        \n        \n

\n                Ubuntu's Apache2 default configuration is different from the\n                upstream default configuration, and split into several files optimized for\n                interaction with Ubuntu tools. The configuration system is\n                **fully documented in\n                /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz**. Refer to this for the full\n                documentation. Documentation for the web server itself can be\n                found by accessing the manual if the apache2-doc\n                package was installed on this server.\n\n

\n

\n                The configuration layout for an Apache2 web server installation on Ubuntu systems is as follows:\n

\n

```
\n/etc/apache2/\n|-- apache2.conf\n|       --  ports.conf\n|-- mods-enabled\n|       |-- *.load\n|-- *.conf\n|-- conf-enabled\n|       -- *.conf\n|-- sites-enabled\n|-- *.conf\n
```

\n          \n

\n                           apache2.conf is the main configuration\n                           file. It puts the pieces together by including all remaining configuration\n                           files when starting up the web server.\n

\n\n

\n                           ports.conf is always included from the\n                           main configuration file. It is used to determine the listening ports for\n                           incoming connections, and this file can be customized anytime.\n

\n\n

\n                           Configuration files in the mods-enabled/,\n                           conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/ directories contain\n                           particular configuration snippets which manage modules, global configuration\n                           fragments, or virtual host configurations, respectively.\n

\n\n

\n                           They are activated by symlinking available\n                           configuration files from their respective\n                           *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed\n                           by using our helpers\n                           \n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2enmod\">a2enmod,\n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2dismod\">a2dismod,\n                           \n                           \n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2ensite\">a2ensite,\n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2dissite\">a2dissite,\n                            \n                                and\n                           \n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2enconf\">a2enconf,\n                                http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2disconf\">a2disconf\n                           . See their respective man pages for detailed information.\n

\n\n

\n                           The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of\n                           environment variables, in the default configuration, apache2 needs to be\n                           started/stopped with /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl.\n                           **Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not work** with the\n                           default configuration.\n

I noticed that it points to a bad char in json file. I checked through the DB and nothing seemed wrong. I even re-created the database with just one field.Furthermore, the error log points to a bug page at

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1288690
```

However, I don't really understand what this page is explaining or where the fix is.How do I solve this replication failed?

Then, i replicated to the IP address instead and got this error:

```
Replication failed: [{couch_api_wrap,db_open,3},
{couch_replicator,init_state,1},
{couch_replicator,do_init,1},
{couch_replicator,init,1},
{gen_server,init_it,6},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]
```